# HTTP-GET Request with Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient() to coutchdb?

Tags: json, titanium, couchdb, titanium-mobile, getjson

Im trying to make a request to my database on Coutch db in Titanium Studio.
I have tried the code bellow, but I get error: Cant retriev data.
If I try with ex url `http://www.appcelerator.com,` I can get the data.
If I use coutch db url `http://127.0.0.1:5984`, I can not get any data + error.
Im wondering if I maybe should use another url?

```
var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
 onload : function(e) {
     Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
     alert('success' + this.responseText);
 },
 onerror : function(e) {
     Ti.API.debug(e.error);
     alert('error');
 },
 timeout : 5000
});
client.open("GET", url);
client.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CouchDB server is run on your local machine and you can access it through `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

When you are running your code in iOS Simulator you have to remember it's virtual environment with different IP. To make proper query from iOS Simulator to CouchDB you have to use your real IP which can be retrieved from `ifconfig` command

```
ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Answer (score -1):

if this 127.0.0.1 is your local address then you should use locallhost.

Example :

```
http://localhost
```